# Adjectival Participle Clause

Tags: past-tense, participle-clauses, reflexive-pronouns

I was reading an article on "Pidgin English" a couple of days ago. It started like this:

" There is a story of a British consul in China who was asked to marry a young Danish sailor and a Chinese girl - no one of the three knowing the other languages.  ..."

This very beginning part of the article left a question in my mind. Here's the question:

Is " ... knowing the other languages" an adjectival participle clause which modifies the noun "three" or even possibly the whole noun phrase " no one of the three"? (I don't really think that it can be a relative clause.)
And IF I am on the right track, which one of the following re-written forms is correct? Why?

1. No one of the three knew the other languages
   Or
2. No one of the three knows the other languages.

Comment: This type of grammar is not really my strong suit, but I think it is an adjectival participle phrase, yes; it describes the manner in which the events took place.  #2 is definitely not correct because the events were in the past - the consul *was* asked - so present tense doesn't match.

Comment: Surely off-topic, but could you provide the link to the article please - the history of Pidgin English is something I've never thought of exploring so far. Would be interesting to read the whole article.

Comment: Although the sense is clear, strictly speaking it should read *no one of the three knowing the others' languages*.

Comment: It's not a modifier; it's the subject of the gerund-participial clause "no one of the three knowing the other languages". "No one of the three" is a fused partitive NP meaning 'no one member of the set of three people'.

Comment: @Rompey: You can find it in a book by Michael Swan named "Understanding Ideas: Advanced Reading Skills" - Cambridge.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is slightly correct.

```
No one of the three knew the other languages.
```

You can make it better by changing it to :

```
No one of the three knew the other's language.
```

The second one *(No one of the three knows the other languages.)* is incorrect because it refers to the present. When you consider the main idea of the whole sentence, it happened in the past.Hence, when re-writing, the new sentence should be in Past Tense.